# Modify order in which screen reader reads a modal dialog

Tags: windows, winapi, modal-dialog, screen-readers

Does anyone have any knowledge regarding screen readers and windows dialog boxes? Specifically how to force the screen reader to read dialog controls in a certain order. *This order has to be determined at run-time as the real dialog controls are added dynamically depending on the type of dialog to be displayed.*

**Note**

I am using a simple Win32 application dialog box. A small example in which I have been able to reproduce my problem is a blank Win32 application and using the default "About" dialog box.

**Background**

I am required to update an existing popup dialog box so that for those users who require a screen reader it will be interpreted and understood correctly. At the moment the screen reader reads the information in a confusing order making it hard for visually impaired users to understand what is required to continue.

**Problem Detail**

I can't seem to update the z-order of controls on the dialog box to change the order in which a screen reader will read them.

As I understand it I have to update the tab-order (z-order) of controls on the dialog box as that is the order with which a screen reader will read the information (feel free to correct me on this point if I'm way off target here).

Many suggestions around the web suggest using either the [SetWindowPos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633545%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function or the [DeferWindowPos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632681%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) functions. Unfortunately I can't get these to work properly.

My "basic" test dialog box has the following controls defined;

```
HWND ctrl_StaticText1 = GetDlgItem(hDlg, IDC_STATIC_1);
HWND ctrl_StaticText2 = GetDlgItem(hDlg, IDC_STATIC_2);
HWND ctrl_StaticText3 = GetDlgItem(hDlg, IDC_STATIC_3);

HWND ctrl_Edit1 = GetDlgItem(hDlg, IDC_EDIT_1);
HWND ctrl_Edit2 = GetDlgItem(hDlg, IDC_EDIT_2);

HWND ctrl_Pict1 = GetDlgItem(hDlg, IDC_PICT_1);

HWND ctrl_ButtonOk = GetDlgItem(hDlg, IDOK);
```

I have then tried to set the z-order as follows;

```
HDWP windowPos = BeginDeferWindowPos(7);

windowPos = DeferWindowPos(windowPos, ctrl_StaticText1, HWND_TOP, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOACTIVATE);
windowPos = DeferWindowPos(windowPos, ctrl_StaticText2, ctrl_StaticText1, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOACTIVATE);
windowPos = DeferWindowPos(windowPos, ctrl_StaticText3, ctrl_StaticText2, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOACTIVATE);

windowPos = DeferWindowPos(windowPos, ctrl_Edit1, ctrl_StaticText3, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOACTIVATE);
windowPos = DeferWindowPos(windowPos, ctrl_Edit2, ctrl_Edit1, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOACTIVATE);

windowPos = DeferWindowPos(windowPos, ctrl_Pict1, ctrl_Edit2, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOACTIVATE);

windowPos = DeferWindowPos(windowPos, ctrl_ButtonOk, ctrl_Pict1, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOACTIVATE);

EndDeferWindowPos(windowPos);
```

When opening the dialog box the screen reader says "static text 1, static text 3, read-only edit" (the read-only edit box being ctrl_Edit1, ctrl_Edit2 isn't read-only).

**Side Note**

When the dialog box simply contained several static text controls this functionality appeared to work correctly, it is only when I started adding more "complex" controls such as the edit boxes and picture controls that the issues appeared.

Thanks for any help :)

**Edit**

As requested, below is the .rc file (I've assumed it's only the dialog control section that is of interest).

```
IDD_ABOUTBOX DIALOGEX 0, 0, 349, 190
STYLE DS_SETFONT | DS_MODALFRAME | DS_FIXEDSYS | WS_POPUP | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU
CAPTION "About"
FONT 8, "MS Shell Dlg", 0, 0, 0x1
BEGIN
    LTEXT           "Static text 1",IDC_STATIC_1,35,25,40,8,NOT WS_GROUP
    LTEXT           "Static text 2",IDC_STATIC_2,33,55,40,8,NOT WS_GROUP
    LTEXT           "Static text 3",IDC_STATIC_3,173,52,40,8,NOT WS_VISIBLE | NOT WS_GROUP
    DEFPUSHBUTTON   "OK",IDOK,292,169,50,14
    EDITTEXT        IDC_EDIT_1, 72, 95, 55, 14, ES_AUTOHSCROLL | ES_READONLY
    CONTROL         "",IDC_PICT_1,"Static",SS_BLACKFRAME,138,92,20,20
    EDITTEXT        IDC_EDIT_2, 174, 95, 40, 14, ES_AUTOHSCROLLs
END
```

*Note, I'd been making some changes while testing so with the above file the screen-reader output is now "static text 1, static text 2, static text 3, read-only edit".* I've tried altering the order in that file, anything after an edit box isn't output by the screen reader.

Comment: The key is to insert the dynamic controls into the dialog at the correct position and in the correct order. So, assuming the controls are stored in an array in the correct order: Create the first control and use SetWindowPos to locate it after the correct existing control (if there is one) and then to use it as the location of the next control. Then you continue creating your dynamic control updating the 'location' control as you go. If this sounds feasible I can produce some sample code.

Comment: @user1793036 Are you suggesting the controls are created through code?  Unfortunately with my actual dialog all the potential controls are already placed on the dialog through the form editor, in relatively the right position, they are then moved and displayed/hidden as needed depending on the information required to be shown.

Comment: @user1793036 I realise my original question said "...the real dialog controls are added dynamically..." What I should have said was "...the real dialog controls are displayed/hidden dynamically, but have all been initially created and placed on the form beforehand..."